# how can I store $data array for all methods in a controller

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, dry

I have some data array which I need for all method's in a controller.

```
          $data['project_ongoing_res_limit']=$this->admin_model->show_project_ongoing_residential_limit();
          $data['project_ongoing_com_limit']=$this->admin_model->show_project_ongoing_commercial_limit();

          $data['project_upcoming_res_limit']=$this->admin_model->show_project_upcoming_residential_limit();
          $data['project_upcoming_com_limit']=$this->admin_model->show_project_upcoming_commercial_limit();

          $data['project_completed_res_limit']=$this->admin_model->show_project_completed_residential_limit();
          $data['project_completed_com_limit']=$this->admin_model->show_project_completed_commercial_limit();
```

Problem is I cant [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) this. so I have paste this $data array in each method.

> I have  a view page for this. so when I load this view , I have to
>   load above $data array each time/method. this is disgusting when controller
>   methods are too much.

I want 1 piece of this code like constructor. How can I do this.

Comment: Hope you are passing these arrays to view. If so, then you can set these $data values in your template library.

Answer (score 0):

you can use traits for this.
Define your methods in a trait, and then use the trait in the controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You can make one `helper class` in which make a `function` and put your above code in it but make sure you can't access `model` using `$this` so, you need to create `CI instance` and than access it. after that in your `controller` in `construct` method you just need to call this function but don't forget to load the `helper class` and store it in a variable and pass it along with `view`.

Comment: but how can I use `CI instance`?

Comment: you just need to write code in this way `$ci = &get_instance();` and after that when you call model `$ci->admin_model->show_project_ongoing_residential_limit();` In this way you can call function in helper class

Answer (score 0):

Just create private data variable in your controller class. Than set your data in constructor. Now you can access your data in any method you want.

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller {
    // ...
    private $data;
    // ...
    public function __construct() {
        parent::_construct();

        $this->data = array();

        $this->data['project_ongoing_res_limit']=$this->admin_model->show_project_ongoing_residential_limit();
        $this->data['project_ongoing_com_limit']=$this->admin_model->show_project_ongoing_commercial_limit();

        $this->data['project_upcoming_res_limit']=$this->admin_model->show_project_upcoming_residential_limit();
        $this->data['project_upcoming_com_limit']=$this->admin_model->show_project_upcoming_commercial_limit();

        $this->data['project_completed_res_limit']=$this->admin_model->show_project_completed_residential_limit();
        $this->data['project_completed_com_limit']=$this->admin_model->show_project_completed_commercial_limit();
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: @imran, Did you load the **`admin_model`** inside the **`__construct(){}`** ?

Comment: Change $data to $this->data in constructor.